# Does Softkinetic have drivers for DS525?

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to buy Creative senz 3D camera DS525, under the impression that DS325 is not on sale as far as  I have checked. Do you know if DS525 supports ROS.

Can I use the same softkinetic camera driver ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261220/does-softkinetic-have-drivers-for-ds525?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this](https://www.softkinetic.com/products/depthsensecameras), the DS525 is identical to the DS325, but doesn't come with a 'foot':

> The DS525 (previously called the DS325) [..]

Same [here](https://www.softkinetic.com/support/Forum/aft/1977):

> The DS525, which is identical to the DS325 except it does not come with a "foot", [..]

Barring any differences in electronics / software (which I don't see mentioned anywhere), the software for the DS325 should work with the DS525.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-05-07**:
Yeah! Thank you very much! That was what I was thinking..